# Get properties of a type in a list in a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have below types and dictionary.

```cs
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Party
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<int, List<Party>> Parties
```

I want to get all Id's of Players that are in Parties, into an array. I want to do it in a single linq query and I am a bit lost. Is it possible ?

Comment: You code will not compile

Comment: ofc. it's just pseudo code. anyway thanks.

Comment: @Doruk It is worth putting actual code that compiles into your question. This 1) makes sure that it's unambiguously clear to everyone, and 2) allows people answering your question to copy/paste your code, in order to test their answer

Comment: @canton7 thanks a lot. was in a bit hurry. will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) will act on each `List<Player>` to get the IDs, and the [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) acts on the `List<Party>` to flatten the returned list of IDs

```
Parties.Values.SelectMany(party => party.Players.Select(player => player.Id)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the mix of [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) and [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) is confusing, you can also write this using (the longer) query syntax:

```
var result = (from partyList in Parties.Values
              from party in partyList
              from player in party.Players
              select player.Id).ToArray();
```

Comment: I generally dislike query syntax, but this is much easier to understand than the `SelectMany`, +1